# set the attribute is not working in IE using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In IE browser alone, set the attribute element is not working using j query. Is there any alternative way to set the attribute using j query or java script. See the below snippet which is not working in IE alone.

```
obj_KLImages.each(function(){
$(this).attr('src', ishttpHead($(this).attr('longdesc')));
});
```

Comment: HTML please? Can you make a JSFiddle for it?

Comment: Try `this.setAttribute()` instead of `$(this).attr()` (it doesn't exactly answer the question, but it might work for you)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function instead of attr().

```
obj_KLImages.each( function() {
  $(this).prop('src', ishttpHead($(this).prop('longdesc')));
});
```

You can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for a discussion of when to you prop() and attr().